# NodeJs Express 4 async function in model seems to return prior to finishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to organize my project by separating some of the logic.  I have routes, views, models, and controllers folders.

For a model called data (models/datamodel.js) I have two methods to get data to populate drop downs.  The methods use sequelizer to query some data async.  I have no problem using sequelizer on the same page to a resolve callback and a reject callback.  But in my data.js, which is a web service page that will return json from a get function, I am using the object created from the dataModel with .then and .catch to handle the callbacks but the execution seems to jump immediately to the resolve callback.  I've tried all kinds of tweaking the structures, promises, and await.  Nothing seems to work.

[models/dataModel.js]

```
'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

function dataModel() {

}



const sequelize = new Sequelize('compliance', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'WIN-QFHT5FIC1UQ',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    requestTimeout: 300000,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 30000
    }
});
var selectTo = sequelize.define('SelectTo',
    {
        to_jid: Sequelize.CHAR(100)
    }
)
var selectFrom = sequelize.define('SelectFrom',
    {
        from_jid: Sequelize.CHAR(255)
    }
)

dataModel.prototype.getSelectTo = async function () {
    sequelize.query('SELECT To_jid from vwTo_jid_select order by to_jid', { model: selectTo }).then(selectTo => {
        return (selectTo); //<-- This returns a valid string array
    }
    ).catch(err => {
        return (err);
    });

};
dataModel.prototype.getSelectFrom = async function () {
     sequelize.query('SELECT from_jid from vwFrom_jid_select order by to_jid', { model: selectFrom })
        .then(selectFrom => {
            return (selectFrom); //<-- returns a valid string array
        }, err => {
            return (err);
        })
}
module.exports = dataModel;
```

[routes/data.js]

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var dataModel = require('../models/dataModel.js');
var dm = new dataModel();

router.get('/:type', function (req, res) {
    switch (req.params.type) {
        case 'selectFrom':
            {

                dm.getSelectFrom().then(
                    result => function () {
                        res.json(result) //<-- code execution jumps here before the SQL Query returns
                    }).catch(err => function () {
                        res.send(err);
                    });

            };

        case 'selectTo':
            {
                dm.getSelectTo().then(
                    result => {
                        res.json(result); //<-- code execution jumps here before the SQL Query returns
                    }).catch(err =>  {
                        res.send(err);
                    });
            }
        default:
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Put your calls to `sequalize.query()` in `try / catch` blocks. I suspect Sequalize is throwing, but is masked by the promise and you don't see it.

Comment: I added a try catch block around the sequelizer query, but I get the same results.  When running in debug, the code execution jumps first to data.js line 26 where the results should arrive after the query runs...Then it jumps to dataModel.js with a valid query results and no errors.

Comment: Wait - so everything works as you expect, but your debugger is wacky? Have you tried debugging in a different browser? this could be a case as simple as a map file being wonky after a file edit or something.

Comment: Duh...of course you are. Tired. Anyway, if it is working correctly, it is likely just your debugger that is wonky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're having problems because your async functions aren't actually returning anything. Just add `return` statements and see if that helps:

```
dataModel.prototype.getSelectTo = async function () {
    // add a return here
    return sequelize.query('SELECT To_jid from vwTo_jid_select order by to_jid', { model: selectTo }).then(selectTo => {
        return (selectTo); //<-- This returns a valid string array
    }
    ).catch(err => {
        return (err);
    });

};
dataModel.prototype.getSelectFrom = async function () {
     // add a return here
     return sequelize.query('SELECT from_jid from vwFrom_jid_select order by to_jid', { model: selectFrom })
        .then(selectFrom => {
            return (selectFrom); //<-- returns a valid string array
        }, err => {
            return (err);
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I noticed the extra return on some examples but didn't quite know how to work it in or why its required.

Comment: Basically, async functions always return a `Promise`, right? So if you don't return anything from the async function you're basically returning `Promise<undefined>`. Anything you need to run _after_ the async function won't wait for anything _inside_ the async function to finish unless you return the `Promise` (in your case the query) you want to wait for.

Comment: Thanks I see it now because its in that anonymous async function I need the return for the .then

Comment: As an aside, you don't actually need those to be async functions since you're not using the `await` keyword. You could just refactor them to normal functions since they return your query `Promise`.